# Rename files with a batch but only the ones ending on "*D.txt"

Tags: batch, rename

I want to rename all the files in a single directory but only txt-files that end with a `D`.

Here is what I tried in a batch... but both didn't work.

-----try1-----

```
@echo off
 set Quelle="C:\temp\TEST\IN\"
 Set DateiFilter="*D.txt"
 for /r %Quelle% %%i in (%DateiFilter%) do rename %%i %%~niI.txt
 end
```

-----try2-----

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set Quelle="C:\temp\TEST\IN\"
Set DateiFilter="*.txt"
set y="D"
set z="I"
for /r %Quelle% %%i in (%DateiFilter%) do (set x=%%i rename "%%i" "!x:D.txt=I.txt!")
pause
end
```

Comment: thank you! :-) I did format it but it didn't recognize my carriage returns. sorry ;)

Comment: +1 Great first question. Can you confirm what you mean by "didn't work". Did they copy at all, did nothing copy, did all files copy?

Comment: You may want to use For %%f in (*D.txt) do rename "%%f" "%%~newName.txt"

Comment: Thank you @DaveRook!
This does rename it with adding a "I" correctly to the files with a D at the end.
But how can I REPLACE the D?

1234D.txt --> 1234I.txt (D gets replaced by I)
1234X.txt --> 1234X.txt (stays the same)

THANK YOU :)

Comment: done...
this does the Job:

@echo off
pushd "C:\temp\TEST\IN\"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "*D.txt" /b /a-d ') do (
   set "name=%%~na"
   set "name=!name:~0,-1!I"
   ren "%%a" "!name!%%~xa")
popd
pause

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments of OP

```
@echo off 
pushd "C:\temp\TEST\IN\" 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "*D.txt" /b /a-d ') do (
   set "name=%%~na" 
   set "name=!name:~0,-1!I" 
   ren "%%a" "!name!%%~xa"
)
popd 
pause
```